# Django Celery: Function only runs once within True While Loop

Tags: python, django, celery

Background: I am using celery to run a python script within a django environment to measure weight from a load cell using a raspberry pi. I am measuring a bottle of water and it relays the information to the webserver.

The python code below runs perfectly when ran in a python environment outside of celery, but when it is ran by a celery worker, the value from the hx.get_weight(5) function within the while loop never changes after the first iteration.

This coded runs fine and the hx.get_weight(5) returns a different value everytime (weight is changing) when not ran by a celery worker. So, I believe it is celery that is causing this issue.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
from .hx711 import HX711, L287

app = Celery('robobud', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.task
async def pump(program_id, amount1, amount2):

    def cleanAndExit():
        print ("Cleaning...")
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print ("Bye!")
        sys.exit()

    ### Weight Class
    hx = HX711(5, 6 )
    hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")
    hx.set_reference_unit(112)
    hx.reset()
    hx.tare()



    ### Weight
    while True:
        try:

            val = hx.get_weight(5)
            print val

            hx.power_down()
            hx.power_up()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is there an `except` corresponding to your `try` block?

Comment: I'm guessing there's either an `except` that's getting triggered that calls `cleanAndExit` or `cleanAndExit` is called in a `finally` or *after* your `try` block

Comment: As C.Nivs said, the cause of this can be in except block, would you mind update the cose and let us see ?

Comment: I was running the wrong file of code, the val = hx.get_weight(5) was outside the while loop....